# why Iam I getting excel VBA's "object required" error when I have supplied an object?

Tags: vba, object, excel, required

My main macro calls 4 sub macros and then executes a single line of code that then generates the "object required" error. I can't figure out why, as I am supplying an object (at least I think I am).

My code looks like this:

```
Sub main_macro()
    Call Mac1
    Call Mac2
    Call Mac3
    Call Mac4
    Range("B" & input1.Row).Value = Range("C" & scenario1.Row)     <-- this generates the error
End Sub

Sub Mac1()
   Dim input1 As Range
End Sub

Sub Mac2()
   Dim scenario1 As Range
End Sub

Sub Mac3()
   Set input1 = Range("A:A").Find("location1", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
End Sub

Sub Mac4()
   Set scenario1 = Range("A:A").Find("location2", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than making them all macros and calling them, put your code from each into the main macro. Variables are in scope only inside a sub unless you sign them to a "global" variable.

Comment: Yeah, I actually had it all in 1 macro to begin with but as I am doing this MANY times, I got the "procedure too large" error, so I decided to break it up.

Comment: looks like adding the "public" declaration at the top of the module fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that what I was implying? :) Also it is important that you handle the output correctly if you are using `.Find` as shown below.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

Your variables are declared inside procedures and are not available to others. And hence you they don't get to initialize.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main_macro()
    Dim input1 As Range, scenario1 As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Change this to the relevant Sheet
        Set input1 = .Range("A:A").Find("location1", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If input1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "location1 not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Set scenario1 = .Range("A:A").Find("location2", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If scenario1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "location2 not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        .Range("B" & input1.Row).Value = Range("C" & scenario1.Row).Value
    End With
End Sub
```